# Error Targeting Instance name from document class AS3

Tags: actionscript, instance, document

I have a document class with this function on it, it targets a symbol with an instance name of scene4_headlights on the stage:

```
function accUpdate(e:AccelerometerEvent):void{
   scene4_headlights.rotation += (e.accelerationX*10);
}
```

But I keep getting error 1120: Access of undefined property scene4_headlights even though I have a symbol on the stage with the instance name of scene4_headlights..

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
package  {

        import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
        import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent; //importing everything you need is cruicial
        import flash.display.MovieClip;

        public class CustomClassName extends MovieClip //your custom class can extend the type of class you used to create your scene4_headlights instance (some prefer using Sprite when the timeline is not required)
            {

            private var accelerometer = new Accelerometer(); //declare a variable data type: Accelerometer

            public function CustomClassName() {
                // constructor code
                accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, accUpdate); // add an eventlistener to the variable you just created
            }

            public function accUpdate(e:AccelerometerEvent): void //declare the function handling the eventlistener
            {
                scene4_headlights.rotation += (e.accelerationX*10);
                trace("The function accUpdate is linked properly"); //trace is your friend
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I did that there, but now I get an error of unable to create the property on the stage... It's really annoying.

Comment: It seemed that the instance of a symbol you are targeting is on the stage already. It would be easier to solve this if you show your entire code, and the error message.